# Looking for the name of an on-base stat that I am sure exists

Tags: baseball, statistics

I'm looking for a stat for how often a hitter gets on base via walk, hit, hit by ball. Anything excluding homeruns.
As in the percentage of time people  actually stand on a base.

Answer (score 2):

[On base percentage](http://m.mlb.com/glossary/standard-stats/on-base-percentage) (OBP) includes all methods of getting on base, but does *not* exclude home runs.  All methods of reaching base safely are included except for errors, reached on a fielder's choice, or dropped third strike.

The only major hitting stat that excludes home runs is [Batting Average on Balls In Play](http://m.mlb.com/glossary/advanced-stats/babip) (BABIP), which also would not include walks or HBPs.

The only area I would imagine a statistician might be interested in times on base (but not home runs) would be in evaluating baserunning, perhaps to use as a denominator; I do not believe there is a named statistic for that, though, they would simply use the OBP numerator and subtract home runs directly.

Comment: Even then, simply being on base doesn't mean you have the opportunity to steal, if the base ahead of you is occupied.

Comment: @chepner Note I said "baserunning" not "stealing"  - baserunning in general is possible to evaluate even without stealing.  But of course there are always complexities with any of these.

Comment: Is there a homerun percentage?  Maybe I could just subtract the two.

Comment: There is HR%, yes.

Answer (score -2):

I would guess you're referring to On Base Percentage (https://www.baseball-reference.com/bullpen/On_base_percentage).

Comment: I believe that includes homeruns.